# Downloading files from an sftp site - how?

Tags: sftp

I have the username and password.

Using Firefox, the URL ftp://myuid@ftp.xxx.com pops a dialogue asking fo the password. The the response is '503 User not logged in'
Using IE, the URL ftp.xxx.com pops a dialogue asking for username and password; the response is the same as with Firefox.

How do I connect to the site?

If not using a browser, can I connect from the command line?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5):

SFTP has nothing to do with FTP, except inasmuch as both are for transferring files.  Firefox out of the box doesn't speak SFTP, last i heard.

In order to download something via SFTP, you'll need an SFTP *client*, like WinSCP. or PSFTP (part of PuTTY).  Both are free.  Or, apparently, there's a FF addon called [FireFTP](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fireftp/?src=search).

Comment: With a ftp site, I can get to the site using a browser & download the files. I have the add-on FIreFTP loaaded with Firefox.

Comment: I am missing something, obviously since I keep getting the 503 error.

Comment: 503 is an FTP or HTTP error, not SFTP.  I haven't used FireFTP, so i'm not sure how to tell it which protocol to use...but you'll need to tell it to use SFTP (usually on port 22) instead if that's how you were told to connect.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I'll re-try with more care.

Comment: Downloaded the files using FireHTP.

Comment: There is FileZilla that accepts sftp connection